# why two different result when using int and BigInt in scala?

Tags: scala

I was doing exercise from "Scala for the Impatient" and I found that I get two different result based on var type I choose from Int and BigInt.

I think I am overlooking something trivial but don't know what? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Why do I get two different result with following two code snippet?

```
var mul:BigInt= 1
for(i<-"Hello") mul = mul * i
print(mul) // mul = 9415087488

var mul:Int = 1
for(i<-"Hello") mul = mul * i
print(mul) // mul = 825152896
```

Comment: Because `9415087488` (~ `10^10`) is bigger than `Int.MaxValue` (~`2 * 10^9`). See [Integer@wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: ah. yes. silly me. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: you may want to include information like the output for problems like this. more information makes your question clearer.

Comment: Also: you don't need to use `var` here, you could use `"Hello".map{i => i: BigInt}.product` or `"Hello".foldLeft(1: BigInt){_*_}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get the comments into an answer here, so the question can be resolved...

1) `BigInt` is bigger than `Int`; specifically, it's bigger than `Int.MaxValue`.  Your second example is overflowing and `9415087488` is the correct answer.

2) Using vars like this is strongly discouraged in Scala. A more "functional" solution is to map the characters to BigInts then use `.product`

```
"Hello".map(BigInt(_)).product
```